# local uniqueness vs global uniqueness

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I'm taking a first course on ODE and i've been asked to provide an example of an  IVP which checks the local uniqueness property but does not check the global uniqueness property. My question is about the  difference between the two types of uniqueness and on what occasions an IVP has one kind of uniqueness or another.
On the other hand , what kind of uniqueness is offered by Picard-Lindelöf  theorem?

Any help is useful!

Comment: Failing global uniqueness could mean that the solution at the IC is locally unique, but may encounter another solution tangentially? For instance a Clairaut equation where the singular solution is nowhere locally unique and you can construct solutions that have regular-singular-regular segments?